# How does the server stop the request that is already being processed?

Tags: java, request, response, spring-cloud, kill-process

My server received a request and it has been processed for a long time. How do I stop it? For example, I want to stop all requests that have been processed for 2s and throw an exception.

I am using spring cloud.

Comment: You can set a property 'connecion time-out' based on the server you're using. and add the property value as '2s'

Answer (score 1):

Configure connection time out in tomcat server.xml.

connectionTimeout
The number of milliseconds this Connector will wait, after accepting a connection, for the request URI line to be presented. Use a value of -1 to indicate no (i.e. infinite) timeout. The default value is 60000 (i.e. 60 seconds) but note that the standard server.xml that ships with Tomcat sets this to 20000 (i.e. 20 seconds). Unless disableUploadTimeout is set to false, this timeout will also be used when reading the request body (if any).

Setting communication timeouts is very important to improve the communication process. They help to detect problems and stabilise a distributed system.

To increase the connection timeout on tomcat server follow the below steps:

1. Open the file server.xml residing in tomcat/conf/.
2. You just need to set variable connectionTimeout in it to Value in Milliseconds.(i.e 1000 milliseconds = 1 second)

Please refer below link to configure connection timeout for spring cloud

https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-config/2.0.0.RELEASE/single/spring-cloud-config.html#_setting_http_connection_timeout